# Format a column in a Syncfusion's GridGroupingControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, syncfusion, gridgroupingcontrol

I have a Syncfusion's [GridGroupingControl](http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/asp.net/grid/html/374c6501-e32b-f204-6992-db704642d1fa.htm).

I try to format a column in a custom format.

My column values are like "000123" and I would like to display it like "123"(removing leading zero, or, what is the same, display just first 3 chars that corresponds to the decimal format "D3")

I tried the following code that does not work:

```
private void ggcResult_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ggcResult.TableDescriptor.Columns.Contains("MY_COL"))
    {
        var col = ggcResult.TableDescriptor.Columns["MY_COL"];
        col.Appearance.AnyCell.Format = "D3";
    }
}
```

Or is too late or too soon, anyway, the column is displayed like "000123"...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution ot my problem... 
It was in the FORMAT of the column data... considered to be as "String", but "string" can't be formatted like an "int" to the "D7" format.

So the solution was to change that format:

```
private void ggcResult_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ggcResult.TableDescriptor.Columns.Contains("MY_COL"))
    {
        var col = ggcResult.TableDescriptor.Columns["MY_COL"];
        // setting the type for corresponding format --------------
        col.Appearance.AnyCell.CellValueType = typeof(int);
        col.Appearance.AnyCell.Format = "D3";
    }
}
```